# How to display plist files in Android cocos2d

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi,

I am doing one  using cocos2d. I want to display animation using plist file. I tried using plist but I didn't get.

My code:

```
public class GamestartLayer1 extends CCColorLayer {

    CGSize winSize;
    CCSpriteFrameCache  cache;
    CCSpriteSheet spriteSheet;
    protected GamestartLayer1(ccColor4B color) {
        super(color);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().displaySize();
        CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().addSpriteFrames("anim_default.plist");
        spriteSheet = CCSpriteSheet.spriteSheet("anim_default.png");
        spriteSheet.setAnchorPoint(0, 0.5f);
        spriteSheet.setPosition(CGPoint.make(0, winSize.height/2));

        this.addChild(spriteSheet);
    }

    public static CCScene scene() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
        CCColorLayer layer = new GamestartLayer1(ccColor4B.ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255));

        scene.addChild(layer);
        return scene;
    }
}
```

But I am getting write screen.

Answer (score 0):

You are only adding the frames to the spritesheet and adding the spritesheet to the layer. You need to pull frames from the spritesheet (I'm used to objective-c so the syntax may be wrong) using something like `CCSpriteFrame frame = CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().spriteFrameByName('framename');` and then creating a sprite object/`ccanimation` from that/those frames